# CMake : add_executable not generating an executable under windows OS

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate an executable with CMake under windows by command line.

This is what I do: 
I enter testprog directory then do

```
 cd build
 cmake ..
```

I also tried this:

```
cd build
cmake -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" ..
```

same result as earlier attempt.

This builds bunch of files in build directory but no executable is ever created.
It creates files to be opened in visual studio.

This is how my folder look like;

```
testprog
      -build
      -src
             -main.cpp
             -call.h
      -include
            -main.h
            -call.h
      -CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(testprog)

include_directories(include)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(testprog ${SOURCES})
```

Answer (score 3):

> This builds bunch of files in build directory but no executable is ever created. It creates files to be opened in visual studio.

That's it.

That's exactly what CMake does; CMake is a *meta build system* where it generates all necessary files that you can open with, say, Visual Studio on Windows since you've given:

```
-G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
```

and build the projects with Visual Studio.

`add_executable` does not magically build your source files. It only tells the given tool to do so.

It's all same in Unix-like platforms as well; CMake drops Makefile, and then you build with `make`. (Or other tools like [Ninja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_(build_system)) can be a good candidate instead of `make`)

**EDIT**

> I understand, but is there no way to build the executable from command line without the need of say Visual studio

Yes, you can! Microsoft provides [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-) for those who don't want the whole heavy IDE.

This is quite common when it comes to establishing a [build server](https://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/Build-Server).

Comment: I understand, but is there no way to build the executable from command line without the need of say Visual studio ?

Comment: So what are the dependencies just to understand correctly. To create an executable I need an IDE ? How can I list the dependencies for Linux and Windows to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build you have to call `cmake --build <dir> [<options>] [-- <build-tool-options>]`

Documentation is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project)

Comment: Great thanks ! This builds a Debug folder. How can copy my "input" directory to that folder ? because if I run the .exe directly from Debug folder it will not work since the input files are not in the same directory as the .exe